# What is the exact industry-standard programming protocol used for writing bits to a Flash memory device?

Tags: flash, non-volatile-memory

I have come across a Program & Verify technique. But I am unsure if that's how data is written to Flash memories in practice. I need a detailed specific protocol, preferably with the relevant numbers.

Thanks!

Comment: For a detailed protocol, you should have told us what specific device you had in mind. The answers below amount to RTFD (the EE equivalent of [RTFM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM)).

Answer (score 3):

The process is slightly different depending in the flash device. You can find that info in the datasheet for the part you're trying to program.  Beyond that there is no "industry standard".

Comment: Agreed, there are so many flash chips with all sorts of different interfaces (serial, parallel) there can't really be a "standard"

Answer (score 2):

Read the datasheet of the device in question.  There are some JEDEC standard Flash device ID and programming methods for NAND FLASH devices - those are documented in the databooks as well.